# function with pointer to struct in another file gives "error: expected ')' before '*' token"

Tags: c, pointers, struct, token

I have a struct declared in program.h

```
typedef struct{
    int size;
    int colour;
    int h;
    int w;
}model;
```

I use it in program.c but I also want to use it in interface.c in a function.

in interface.h I have

```
#include "program.h"

void updateF(model* novomodelo);
```

in interface.c

```
#include "interface.h"

void updateF(model* novomodelo){
....
}
```

but I'm getting

> error: expected ')' before '*' token

What am I doing wrong?
What is the correct way to do this?
thanks

Comment: You need to use `#include "program.h"` and `#include "interface.h"`. You are missing the `"`s (the double quotes) in the posted code. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include for further details.

Comment: Code is with "s. I forgot the double quotes in the post. edited. thanks

Comment: Agreed with R Sahu. But also make sure your compiler supports anonymous structs; it if doesn't, change `typedef struct {` to `typedef struct model {`

Comment: After the fix to the `#include` lines, the code looks ok to me. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you but it hasn't solved.

Comment: Untagged structs are perfectly standard, @torstenvl, at least all the way back to C89.  Are you thinking of a particular compiler?  Because if I ever ran into one that rejected untagged structure types then I would be try to keep it as far away from me as possible.

Comment: @mehrlicht, I'm inclined to think that the picture is different than you have portrayed.  The error message you present appears to indicate that the compiler does not recognize `model` as a type name, But the code fragments you present suggest that it should do.  This is why we generally expect questions to demonstrate the problem via a *bona fide* [mcve].  Your code fragments do not constitute an MCVE, and we are unlikely to help you until you provide one.

Comment: I think I solved it.
Somehow I needed to have interface.c like this:

    #include "interface.h"

    struct model;
    void updateF(struct model* novomodelo){
    ....
    }

Comment: @John Bollinger You seem to be right (and thanks for the correction on terminology - anonymous `struct`s are wholly different from untagged ones). I know lack of support for using `typedef` on an untagged `struct` had bitten me in the butt before... if I had to guess it would have been on an old 32-bit SPARC machine running SunOS 5-point-something-or-other. Good times.

Comment: @mehrlicht That isn't a solution, it's a workaround. Somehow your typedef isn't functioning and propagating correctly. You should try and figure out why.

Comment: That workaround led to an error later on so I had to find another turnaround which was declaring the functions in the headers where the structs are and defining those functions in the c's that I wanted....